# How to enable anti-aliasing on Qlabel?

Tags: qt, antialiasing, qlabel

My QLabels look quite ugly, it seems that there's no anti-aliasing. How can I enable this feature (assuming it's available)?

Comment: This is a very wild guess since I don't have experience with Qt, but does setting a background color solve the problem ? Many UI systems don't do font anti-aliasing without a background since the aliased pixels depend on a background color to blend in to.

Comment: You probably should tell what OS you are using. My QLabels look just fine.

Comment: Are you using Qt software rendering (raster) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
QLabel * l = new QLabel();
QFont f=l->font();
f.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
l->setFont(f);
```

you may also alter application font settings, to be applied to all widgets you use...

```
QFont f=QApplication::font();
f.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
QApplication::setFont(f);
```

Comment: Remember that iz is `QFont::PreferAntialias`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Antialisasing attribute in the label's font to PreferAntialias.
You can do it in QtCreator or by code like this :

```
QFont f("Times", 50);
f.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
ui->label->setFont(f);
```

Hope this helps